# Number of divisors 888,888.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

For an hour, the number of questions at math.stackexchange.com will reach 888,888. This number has exactly $2^7 = 128$ divisors. Which next integer will have the same number of divisors?

Comment: The next six are $$890568, 891480, 893970, 895104, 895752, 896280$$

Comment: @Moo how you can find them?

Comment: I cheated using: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Length%5BDivisors%5B888888%5D%5D, if you want to see them, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Divisors%5B888888%5D

Comment: but there is only 888888 divisors. How you find 890568 and others?

Comment: I just ran a loop that printed the next number that had $128$ divisors - it took about a second to code and run.

Comment: I am curious whether actually this number of questions will be reached within the predicted time. Chances seem to be very good.

Comment: @Moo A second to code ?

Comment: It seems there is no easy way to prove that there is no number before 890568 without checking the candidate numbers manually. We can exclude the odd candidates cause the smallest odd number with 128 divisors is $3^3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 17\gg 890568$, but that still leaves us with about 800 even candidates. A priori, it does not seem impossible to have anumber $2^3$ times 5 different odd primes in that range

Comment: @Peter Just as fast to code in PARI/GP: `n=888889; while(numdiv(n)!=128,n++);n`

Comment: @Peter please upvote if it will be or downvote if it not appear

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But you have to find this code, enter it and let it run. This will take a bit more than one second ...

Comment: The great moment is there!

Comment: @Peter my mistake)